How to Train a Model on the Whole Outer-loop Training Set in Nested Cross-validation?
I'm implementing nested cross-validation for a machine learning project and need some clarity on the training process using the outer-loop training set. Here’s a summary of my process:

Outer-loop partitioning: Splits the data into several training and test sets.
Inner-loop partitioning: Within each outer-loop training set, further splits are made into training and validation sets to optimize hyperparameters.
Model training and evaluation: Once the best hyperparameters are determined via the inner loop, the model is trained on the entire outer-loop training set and then evaluated on the outer-loop test set.

My concerns are:

In scenarios like training deep learning models, monitoring overfitting is crucial and typically done by observing the validation loss. How can one manage this when the model is trained on the entire outer-loop training set, which lacks a separate validation set?
Similarly, for classification tasks, determining the optimal threshold for making decisions is often based on validation set performance. Without a separate validation set in this final training phase, how can one effectively set this threshold?

Can anyone suggest strategies or best practices for addressing these issues in the context of nested cross-validation?
Thanks
